# python and sqlite failing to insert on violating unique constraint

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, integrity

I have a large body of text and I am trying to count all the words in it to get their frequencies. It is too big to keep a dictionary in memory so I am using sqlite for this task. I wrote a Database class and used the word as a primary key because it should be unique.

Somewhere in the process it is failing because the word 'frequency' is trying to be added twice. I have no idea why this could be happenning as there were many other common words that must have been counted twice already... Here are my two files....

dbmaker.py

```
import sqlite3
import sys



class Database():
    '''Creates an object with method for adding and checking words against an sqlite database'''

def __init__(self):
    self.dbname = raw_input('What will be the name of this database: ')
    self.table1 = 'words'
    self.column1 = 'word_name'
    self.column1t = 'TEXT'
    self.column2 = 'frequency'
    self.column2t = 'INTEGER'
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.dbname)
    self.c = self.conn.cursor()
    self.c.execute('CREATE TABLE {tn} ({nf} {ft} PRIMARY KEY)'.\
        format(tn=self.table1, nf=self.column1, ft=self.column1t))
    self.c.execute('ALTER TABLE {tn} ADD COLUMN {cn} {ct}'.\
        format(tn=self.table1, cn=self.column2, ct=self.column2t))
    self.conn.commit()
    self.checkfile = open('check.txt', 'w+')



def check_word(self, word_name):
    exist = self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn} WHERE {cn}="{wn}"'.\
        format(tn=self.table1, cn=self.column1, wn=word_name))

    exist = self.c.fetchall()
    if exist:
        new_freq = exist[0][1] + 1
        self.c.execute("UPDATE {tn} SET {c2n}={en} WHERE {c1n}='{word}'".\
            format(tn=self.table1, c2n=self.column2, en=new_freq, c1n=self.column1, word=word_name))
        return True
    else:
        return False



def add_word(self, word_name, frequency=1):
    self.checkfile.write('%s\n' % word_name)
    self.c.execute('INSERT INTO {tn} ({c1n}, {c2n}) VALUES ("{wn}", {f})'.\
        format(tn=self.table1, c1n=self.column1, c2n=self.column2, wn=word_name, f=frequency))
```

crunch.py

```
import sys
import operator
from dbmaker import Database

db = Database()
infile = open(sys.argv[1])

for line in infile:
    line = line.split()
    for word in line:
        word=word.lower()
        if not db.check_word(word):
            db.add_word(word)
```

db.conn.commit()
db.conn.close()

Here is my Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crunch.py", line 13, in <module>
    db.add_word(word)
  File "/home/ubuntu/wikicorpus/dbmaker.py", line 44, in add_word
    format(tn=self.table1, c1n=self.column1, c2n=self.column2, wn=word_name, f=frequency))
```

sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: words.word_name

Comment: You are tying to insert the same value for word_name so you get an intgerity error as the values must be unique, how large is the file?

Comment: 14gb...I know they must be unique, but I am checking for uniqueness in the check_word function. I just don't see how anything could slip past that function

Comment: an interesting observation...I tried a spanish language file and it failed on the word 'frequency' as well so thats even more baffling

Comment: Just getting it running, I was getting an error as your format will fail with certain words i.e ones with any `'`

Comment: hmm, yes. Those should all be removed from my file though. Can you see any other situations where it would fail?

Comment: try http://pastebin.com/XM72geb2, I use a unique set of words and got the same error,  there was an issue with your formatting and that seems to have fixed it

Comment: I also left a select in there for debugging, you can remove it

Comment: Thanks so much for your rewrite, but now I am getting a syntax error sometimes...sqlite3.OperationalError: near "famoso": syntax error. Again I have no clue what could be causing this and it runs for a really long time before it occurs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, The syntax error was an error in my data. I had  a few strings with quotes around them that I should have eliminated that was messing with the triple quoted parts. Thanks for the help, if you make it an answer I'll accept it